# Aiohttp issues 400 Bad Request. But requests are working fine

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp

I am trying to make asynchronous POST function using VirusTotal API.

When I use requests everything works fine. But aiohttp gives 400 Bad Request for no reason.

**requests**

```
import requests

headers = {'x-apikey' : '3f211a1a2f3e0092832063970c780db4391d79ba15ee907f7c950d870e54a84f'}

def VirusTotal(path):

    api_url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/files/upload_url'
    query = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
    json = query.json()
    url = json["data"]

    files = {"file": (open(path, "rb").read())}
    result = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)

    result.json() # <-- 200

VirusTotal(path)
```

**aiohttp**

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

headers = {'x-apikey' : '3f211a1a2f3e0092832063970c780db4391d79ba15ee907f7c950d870e54a84f'}


async def VirusTotal(path):

    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    api_url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/files/upload_url'
    query = await session.get(api_url, headers=headers)
    json = await query.json()
    url = json["data"]

    files = {"file": (open(path, "rb").read())}
    result = await session.post(url, headers=headers, data=files)

    await result.json() # <-- 400

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(VirusTotal(path))
```

Comment: I can't recreate this error. It seems that the only error in the the last line: `loop.run_until_complete(VirusTotal(path))` where it says path is not defined.

Comment: Something else, can you explain what you are trying to do?